# PHP / MySQL bulk insert (4000 records) and performance for faceted search

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I'm trying to build the following faceted search solution:

- Read 4000 product prices from different files. Each price has 30 properties
- Get faceted search counts from those 4000 rows
- Read many different selections (by filtering) from those 4000 rows

On a busy moment, our application must be able to process 2000 of these actions in one hour.
The challenge is to be able to read rows and counts as quick as possible.
Also, writing and reading must be done from multiple PHP processes.

As a solution, so far I've chosen to insert those 4000 product prices into a database, and use queries to get counts / selections of rows:

- MySQL Memory: inserting rows takes about 250 ms, reading and counting is very quick (about 2 ms for every SELECT query)
- MySQL InnoDB: inserting rows takes about 600 ms, reading and counting is a bit slower (about 5 ms for every SELECT query)
- Elasticsearch: inserting rows takes about 250 ms, but must be done with a bulk insert (HTTP request). Waiting for index ready takes about 250 ms more. (500 total). Reading and counting works differently (with aggregation), but can be very quick.

This comparison has not been completely fair, because for MySQL i've been using prepared statements instead of a bulk insert. (also, because the bulk insert is a disadvantage and only used with elastic to prevent 4000 slow HTTP requests).

The performance from MySQL Memory tables seems to be great and acceptable, even with 4 million records in the storage. But I'm a bit worried about the scalability and stability of this solution.

Other explored options are:

- Apache ignite (but was not able to get it to work with PHP 7)
- MemSQL (too expensive)
- VoltDB (only PHP 5.3, not PHP 7)
- MongoDB (performance like elasticsearch)

I've also thought about solutions without using a database (with a lot of calculations / loops in PHP), but this is far from ideal because the process of reading and inserting the 4000 product prices must be done in multiple PHP processes (for speed).

What other (database) solutions could be a better fit here? It's about the mix of writing and reading data as quick as possible.

Comment: So all this and no hardware mentioned? You measured insert of a single row? Use transactions when inserting instead of bulk inserts, you can kick in a few thousand inserts in a fraction of a second on an ssd these days. Using materialized views stops repeating counting as it's wasteful. I didn't understand what you're solving, but you're not mentioning hardware nor MySQL config at all - doing this kind of test without optimal config is meaningless.

Comment: I understand hardware is an important part of the solution, but I'm open for any suggestions on that. I've tested on a mac book pro with SSD, but also on a large VPS platform. And also with elasticsearch running on an expensive dedicated machine with ssd and lots of memory.

I understand these benchmarks/indications are not worth a lot without specifics (hardware & config). But I was hoping that someone could point me in directions for other solutions, based on these indications.

Comment: MySQL isn't so good for searching. I would stick with the elasticsearch solution, since it allow more complex searchs with for sure the fastest response, easy scalability and replication if needed.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. Dealing with only 4000 records is fast using any of the storage systems you mentioned. Elasticsearch is great when you have a ton of unstructured data that you want to search - but its syntax isn't as easy as SQL is. If you're looking for performance - MySQL / ES / MongoloidDB are fast enough, with space to tune (especially MySQL). Now, creating a query for ES isn't the same as with MySQL. It will boil down to this: what are you most comfortable working with? Which of the mentioned do you know how to use the best?

Comment: Basically, you need to pick one that you like. As in, subjectively. Objectively, you concluded these are products that are fast. Objectively, they can achieve the same thing. What you're left with is pure opinionated approach  as there's no "best" among them, especially with so little info on your side. In the end, no one prevents you from using MySQL as OLTP and ES for search, there's no rule that there's a single "best" storage solution out there. Personally, I use ES to search the logs and I must admit it's awesome.

Comment: @N.B. I agree that the solutions I mentioned are both fast and acceptable. I've asked this question to make sure I'm not missing any other (maybe even better) solutions.

Comment: Are you shoveling 4000 rows around repeatedly?  Why?  If you are loading 4000 rows only once, then the load time should not matter.

Comment: Give us an example of a typical search.

Comment: @RickJames every search query is different, and the results will be loaded 'live' from other sources. Prices and available products are different all the time.